# Does Windows calculate CRCs to check every file operation?

Tags: windows, checksum, data-integrity, crc

When Windows encounters a file corruption on a file system, it may return the following error message:

> Data error (cyclic redundancy check).

This suggests Windows checks every file operation (copy, move, etc.) by calculating [CRCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).  Does Windows really do this, whether during or after the operation?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1719053/windows-equivalent-to-sha256sum-c-cryptographic-hash-digest-file-recursive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows doesn't actually preform any redundancy on file transfers, this is a misnomer for the device driver accessing a bad sector block (see the SO question [What, and where, is the NTFS CRC windows complains about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662531/what-and-where-is-the-ntfs-crc-windows-complains-about) and [this Microsoft KB article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140423192711/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319128); NTFS does not store any kind of file checksums).  If you receive this error on your computer, you should ensure your hard disk's integrity (and possibly invoke `chkdsk` with the `/r` flag).

Long story short, Windows does not verify any files after they are transferred.  You can use another software tool like [TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) to verify data after moving/copying files.

Comment: I've actually looked at the linked [so] question.  What I'm asking is whether Windows calculates CRCs on the fly during file operations, not necessarily whether it stores them.

Comment: @DragonLord I do not believe it does, otherwise these errors would appear during normal read/write errors where there are not bad sectors reported.  You can use a third-party utility to actually verify file contents once they are transferred.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify.  Does Windows perform any error checking *while a file operation is in progress*?

Comment: @DragonLord in my experience, no.  I have used Windows to copy files to bad drives before, and sometimes have **not** received the error message.  They were only detected when I manually tried to verify the CRC (or MD5/SHA1 hash) of the files and they did not match.  I believe the error message is only shown when the actual disk device driver throws an error during transfer, or the NTFS filesystem itself detects some kind of corruption.

Comment: There are actually three distinct conditions that can cause this error (in the typical IDE/SATA interface to conventional hard drive): 1) Data corruption on the connection between the hard drive and the controller. 2) Data corruption in the data read by the disk controller from the disk surface despite retries. 3) Access to a disk sector known bad by the controller that cannot be remapped until written to.